# Renderizar multiples formularios y validarlos en un solo template en DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Intente renderizar 3 formularios con Class-based views en un solo template pero no tuve éxito, por ello decidí hacer con un método algo así: `def formTortas(request): ....`
donde llamo a mis 3 formularios defendidos en Forms.py de esta forma,

```
    formVenta = VentaForm()
    formTorta = TortaForm()
    formCliente = ClienteForm()
```

y devuelvo a mi vista así

```
return render(request, "tienda/venta_tortas.html", {'formVentaTorta':formVenta,'formTorta': formTorta, 'formCliente': formCliente})
```

Normal puedo acceder a los 3 formularios, y para procesar el contenido de cada formulario lo hago con condiciones y recepciono sus valores de un Form por ejem. de Ventas: `formVenta = VentaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`, si el Usuario ha llenado todos los campos OBLIGATORIOS de un Form se inserta con ÉXITO. El problema surge por ejemplo cuando no llenas los campos obligatorios de un formulario y normalmente debe de devolver el mensaje error de VALIDACIÓN, y ya no me devuelve el ERROR de las validaciones, por el hecho de que los dos formularios ya no me vuelve a renderizar, me arroja este error, por ejemplo cuando intento insertar a `formVenta`.

```
local variable 'formTorta' referenced before assignment
```

Cada formulario asigno a una variable en las condiciones(incluso intente asignar en una variable global pero sigue..), ¿cómo volver a  renderizar a todos los Forms por ejemplo después de validación de errores de cualquiera de los formularios? o algún otro método mas eficiente que puedo emplear?, gracias.

Comment: Puedes pegar el codigo actual de toda la vista, es decir, toda la funcion de `def formTortas(request): ....`, me parece que el error esta alli

Comment: Perdón el código es bastante extenso, al parecer lo he solucionado, lo agregado la llamada a los Forms tanto en el inicio como el la parte Else del POST, algo así.

' def formTortas(request):
   formVenta = VentaForm()
    formTorta = TortaForm()
    formCliente = ClienteForm()
    if request.method == "POST": 
   .......
    else:
        formVenta = VentaForm()
        formTorta = TortaForm()
        formCliente = ClienteForm()'

Gracias

Comment: Hola @AlejandroHurtado, por favor, podrías publicar tu solución como respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: @toledano ahí esta publicado, saludos

Comment: Excelente decisión. Muchas gracias Alejandro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución era inicializar todos los `forms` en la parte superior de la función algo así,
`def formTortas(request):

    form_venta = VentaForm()
    formTorta = TortaForm()
    formCliente = ClienteForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
    ......
    .....`

tanto en la parte de ELSE del If de `Form_valid`

```
else:
    form_venta = VentaForm()
    formTorta = TortaForm()
    formCliente = ClienteForm()
```

y algo así seria el `return` de los `forms`

```
return render(request, "tienda/venta_tortas.html", {'form_venta_torta': form_venta,
                                                    'formTorta': formTorta, 'formCliente': formCliente})
```

Saludos